# Scrapy If Else Inventory Level

Tags: python, scrapy

Currently I am working on a project to keep current inventory levels of an e-commerce site with out a data feed. I have built a spider to collect data and make my own feed however I am running into some problems creating a rule to set inventory to 0 if a "buy it now" button exists or 9 if the "buy it now" button does exist. Any help would be appreciated. Much Thanks!

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from cdaddy.items import CdaddyItem

class CdspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'cdspider'
    allowed_domains = ['cuff-daddy.com']
    start_urls = ['http://cuff-daddy.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        href = CdaddyItem()
        href['url'] = response.url
        # Inventory
        inv = response.css('boolean(btn-buy-now').extract()
        if inv == 'True':
            inv = ('12')
        else:
            inv = ('0')
        # SKU
        sku = response.xpath('//div[5]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/span[2]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to check for the existence of a tag with the class `btn-buy-now` (which is the tag for the `Buy Now` input button), then you are mixing up stuff with your selectors. Exactly you are mixing up `xpath` functions like `boolean` with `css` (because you are using `response.css`).

You should only do something like:

```
inv = response.css('.btn-buy-now')
if inv:
    inv = ('12')
else:
    inv = ('0')
```

because `response.css('.btn-buy-now')` with find something if that exists. If not, then it will return an empty list (which defaults to `False`)

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks for your help and Happy New Year!